# Smallest interval for the value of $\int_0^1\frac{x}{x^3+16} $

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> If the value of
>
> $$\int_0^1\frac{x}{x^3+16} $$ lies in the interval $[a,b]$, then the
>   smallest such interval is?
>
> $a)\;\; [0,\frac{1}{17}]$
>
> $b)\;\; [0,1]$
>
> $c)\;\;[0,\frac{1}{27}]$
>
> $d)$ None of the above

The given integral evaluates to a discrete value ($\approx0.03049$). Also the given integral is not an improper integral then why does the question states a range? Is the question wrong or am I missing something?

Also what does it mean by the smallest such interval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int\limits_0^1\frac{x}{x^3+16}dx<\int\limits_0^1\frac{x}{16}dx=\frac{1}{32}.$$

Comment: ahh I feel like such a fool for not getting this. Nice.

Comment: Why not $$\int\limits_0^1\frac{x}{x^3+16}dx<\int\limits_0^1\frac{x}{x^4+16}dx$$?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Because it does not help to solve the starting problem.

Comment: How do I get to option (C) using $\frac{1}{32}$?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Because $\frac{1}{32}<\frac{1}{27}.$

Comment: How will that be the smallest interval?

Comment: @prog_SAHIL Between a), b) and c) the c) is a smallest, which valid.

Comment: So the question asks the smallest among the given? Thats what had me stuck , Thanks .

Comment: You are welcome!